# Генерация sitemaps в Django

Tags: sitemap, django

Сделал генерацию sitemaps по [этому руководству](http://djbook.ru/ch11s06.html), однако сайт большой, и карта генерится 
 очень долго, больше минуты. Еще и сервер не сильно быстр, так что для него это нагрузка лишняя.

Как сохранять результат генерации в файл (sitemap.xml), а не отдавать по запросу? А поисковик будет его уже брать напрямую из файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вьюха django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap (которая генерит xml) возвращает HttpResponse:

```
return HttpResponse(xml, mimetype='application/xml')
```

Думаю, надо получать его от вьюхи и вытягивать xml (чтобы не менять сам метод)

Т.е. вы генерируете один раз sitemap.xml с помощью django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap, поучаете от нее HttpResponse, из него получаете сам sitemap.xml и сохраняете на сервере. При каждом изменении структуры сайта он должен генериться заново (тут, пожалуй, паттерн Наблюдатель вам поможет). А при обращении к url sitemap.xml должна вызываться другая вьюха, отдающая HttpResponse, в котором будет лежать sitemap.xml

Comment: Подскажите, как переназначить отдачу? Не в исходниках же править.

Или скопировать данную функцию, и просто сделать свою по мотивам этой, с нужным сохранением в конце?
Я думал генерацию карты сайта загнать в cron, или сделать кнопкой в админке.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше кнопкой. По крону может выйти чересчур часто. Но оптимально все же при смене структуры генерировать. тогда карта всегда будет актуальной и не будет холостой нагрузки на сервер.

Comment: В сайтмапе должны ведь отображаться ссылки на все материалы, размещенные на сайте, например, добавил новую статью, уже нужно обновлять сайтмап.

Comment: >при смене структуры генерировать

Как рас это сильно часто. А по cron в 3 часа ночи делать, когда нагрузка на сервер минимальна, ну и все материалы которые вышли за день будут обновлены.

Сайтмап не приказ поисковику, в всего лишь подсказка, для более быстрого сканирования сайта, не думаю что google важно при каждом материале получать новый sitemap.

Comment: Ну, если структура меняется часто - да, согласен, кроном будет гуманнее :)

Comment: Спасибо @Ekkertan за пинок в нужную сторону.

Answer (score 2):

Приведу своё решение, уверен кому-то пригодится. По мотивам ответа [[@Ekkertan](/users/6127/ekkertan)](/users/6127/ekkertan).

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.http import HttpResponse

def generic(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser: #Чтобы никто не начал злоупотреблять
        return HttpResponse('You not admin')

    sitemaps = {
        'news': NewsItemSitemap,
        'articles': ArticleItemSitemap,
    }

    try:
        xml = sitemap(request, sitemaps)

        f = open(settings.ABSOLUTE_MEDIA + 'sitemap.xml', 'w')
        f.write(xml.rendered_content.encode("utf-8"))
        f.close()
        return HttpResponse('Success')
    except:
        return HttpResponse('Error')
```

Таким способом по ссылке привязанной к функции generic, только суперюзер, мы получим файл с сгенерированной картой сайта. Далее остаётся в [urls.py](http://urls.py) написать по адресу /sitemap.xml отдавать файл sitemap.xml

Всё, теперь или в cron задачу ставим, или в админку кнопку - "Генерировать sitemap".

ПС.. Как оказалось в разных версиях Django, разные методы, по этому xml.rendered_content может не сработать. Пишем тогда xml.content или смотрим dir(xml) и выбираем нужный метод.
.encode("utf-8") может понадобится, а может и нет, смотрим по обстоятельствам.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас есть отличное приложение

https://github.com/xaralis/django-static-sitemaps

Answer (score 0):

Все намного проще.

1. Создаете индексный sitemap
2. Юзаете **cache_page()**

Более подробнее [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index).

Читайте официальные доки и будет вам счастье.